# aws redshift connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I get a timeout when trying to connect to my newly set up amazon redshift database.
I tried telnet:

```
telnet redshift-cluster-1.foobar.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com 5439
```

With the same result.

I set the database configuration to "Publicly accessible".

Note that I am just experimenting. I have set up aws services for fun before, but don't have much knowledge of the network and security setup. So I expect it to be a simple mistake I make.

I want to keep it simple, so my goal is just to connect to the database from a local SQL client and I don't care about anything else at this stage :)

It would be great if you could give me some pointers for me to understand what the problem could be and what I should try next.

[image: subnets]

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the Amazon Redshift cluster? Also, if you resolve that DNS name to an IP address (eg with `ping redshift-cluster-1.foobar.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com`), is the IP address a Public IP address or a Private IP address (eg `10.x`).

Comment: It's a public IP (100.x.x.x). The security group is called default, which I guess is the default. It has an inbound rule with IP version: - , type: all traffic, protocol: all, port range: all and an outbound rule with IP version: IPv4, type: all traffic, protocol: all, port range: all, destination: 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Sounds good. Are you sure that the Redshift cluster was launched in a Public Subnet? Have you tried connecting with an SQL client (instead of Telnet)?

Comment: I am not sure that the Redshift cluster was launched in a Public Subnet. How can I check that, or change it so it works? (I'll try to figure it out, but tbh I have no clue where to start.) I tried connecting with mysql-workbench and dbeaver and get a timeout on both.

Comment: When I set the "publicly accessible" to enabled I have the option to specify an elastic IP address, which I left blank in case that is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add a new inbound rule to the security group and set the source to "anywhere-ipv4" or "my ip". The default inbound rule has a source with the name of the security group itself, which might mean that it is only accessible from within the VPC. At least it is not accessible from the outside.

I set the protocol to tcp and type to redshift, which seemed like the sensible choice for my use case.

See the picture for a sample configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can try is to connect to it through an API. To connect to this database using a Java client, you need these values:

```
   private static final String database = "dev";
   private static final String dbUser ="awsuser";
   private static final String clusterId = "redshift-cluster-1";
```

I have never experienced an issue when using the [RedshiftDataClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshiftdata/RedshiftDataClient.html).